# Parameters for atan2() are incorrect in VS2005?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, atan2

There seems to be a mistake in the `math.h` header provided with Visual Studio 2005.

```
double  __cdecl atan2(__in double _Y, __in double _X);

inline float atan2f(__in float _X, __in float _Y)
    {return ((float)atan2((double)_X, (double)_Y)); }
```

The parameters of the atan2f() function seem to be reversed.

I'm not sure if this is the case with later version of Visual Studio. Does anyone know what the score is here?

Comment: Well, some discussion about it: http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=54415.

Check by comparing the results of atan2f(x,y) and atan2f(y,x) if it is typo or they are really in wrong order. Then you will know :)

Answer (score 0):

A difference that has no impact is not worth worrying about.

The compiler (in effect) ignores the names of the arguments of `atan2()` because it is not a definition (i.e. function implementation).  As long as the function definition (implementation) computes arctangent in radians of the first argument divided by the second, the implementation of `atan2()` is correct.

The important thing to avoid a bug in this definition of `atan2f()` is that the first and second argument are passed to `atan2()` in the same order.  That is happening, so (assuming the definition of `atan2()` is correct) there is no functional flaw and an expression `atan2f(a,b)` will compute the arctangent of `a/b` - which is what the standard requires.

The only potential flaw is in understanding by humans what the functions do.   But, generally speaking, it is advisable that humans refer to documentation of standard functions for understanding rather than to the header files.     This is a stylistic flaw, not a functional one.